# how to retrieve created_date_time and created_by using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

*i have create stored procedure,that name is cmtprocedure.i write the stored procedure for insert table and how to write select query for this stored procedure.how to retrive the comment, created_date_time,updated_date_time, created_by,updated_by?*

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[cmtprocedure]
@cmt_Id int = null,
@comments nvarchar(MAX)=null,
@ques_ans_id int=null,
@created_date_time datetime=null,
@updated_date_time datetime=null,
@created_by int=null,
@updated_by int=null,
@Action varchar(100)=null
```

AS
BEGIN

```
 if @Action = 'insert'
```

BEGIN

```
insert into comments(comments,ques_ans_id,created_date_time,updated_date_time,created_by,updated_by)
    values
    (@comments,@ques_ans_id,@created_date_time,@updated_date_time,@created_by,@updated_by)

END
```

BEGIN

```
 select * from comments where comments=@comments and created_date_time=@created_date_time and updated_date_time=@updated_date_time and created_by=@created_by and updated_by=@updated_by 

END
```

END

Comment: You've tagged `mysql` and `sql-server`. Which is correct? This looks like `sql-server` but people won't want to guess./

Comment: Do you want to do CURD using a single stored procedure ?

Comment: sorry,sql server and stored procedure is correct tags